# How can I ensure that 2 <video>s are played at the exact same time (with no lag)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my current code: https://jsfiddle.net/n7u4twb1/10/

Current js code:

```
Data={
  num_files:2
}

Video = {
  preview: {
    play_all: function(){
      for(i=0;i<Data.num_files;i++){
         $('#video'+i).get(0).play();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

With the "Play All" button I encounter lag more than half the time. How can I ensure that the videos are played at the same time with no lag? It is to preview video collages (multiple videos) before they are processed and turned into one video -- I want users to be able to edit the timing at which each video starts but they need a way to preview the collage before the processing starts! Thanks in advance

Comment: check [_this_](https://bocoup.com/blog/html5-video-synchronizing-playback-of-two-videos) which has a functionality to sync.

Comment: I don't think that browser/js is the best environment for this job. You are unlikely ever to realise the kind of precision you seek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a button for each video, add an extra button that uses the `.click()` method. The [`.click()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) method is like jQuery [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) method which when invoked will auto click whatever it's bound to.

### Demo

```js
var ui = document.forms.ui;
var btns = ui.elements;

btns[0].onclick = function(e) {
  play(0);
}

btns[1].onclick = function(e) {
  play(1);
}

btns.vSync.onclick = function(e) {
  btns[0].click();
  btns[1].click();
}

function play(idx) {
  var vids = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('video'));
  var vid = vids[idx];
  if (vid.paused || vid.ended) {
    vid.play();
  } else {
    vid.pause();
  }
}
```

```html
<video src='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4' width='240'></video>
<video src='https://storage04.dropshots.com/photos6000/photos/1381926/20170326/005609.mp4' width='240'></video>

<form id='ui'>
  <button data-id='0' type='button'>VIDEO A</button>
  <button data-id='1' type='button'>VIDEO B</button>
  <button id='vSync' type='button'>SYNC</button>
</form>
```